# Node JS, Using getAccounts() from inside getInitialProps

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Is it possible use web3.eth.getAccounts() from inside the getInitialProps? When I run it it returns an undefined object. It works perfectly everywhere else in the code.

I want to use it to fetch some data from the solidity contract so it requires the user address to get the correct information. I then use this data to display on the page when it loads up.

Is there any other way to achieve this?

I hope my explanation is clear enough.

I am struggling to find any solution to this.
Thanks